# interchangeable select as in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I want to know how to make the `select as` of the `ng-options` attribute interchangeable, I mean, I want it to evaluate if display one or another value; there's an array of jsons that has the following  keys:

```
[
    {id: 1, name: 'christmas', alias: 'xmas'},
    {id: 2, name: 'new year', alias: null}
]
```

So, what I want is to display `name` if `alias` is null, but if `alias` is not null, then display `alias`, what do I need to add to `ng-options`:

```
ng-options="f as f.name for f in vm.festivities"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ng-options="f as (f.alias || f.name) for f in vm.festivities"
```

In JavaScript, `a || b` evaluates to the first truthy operand (or the last one if none of them is truthy)

Comment: Works!, what if I want to evaluate if display one name or another depending on another `<select>` value?

Comment: Can I implement ternary operand(?:) there?

Comment: Same thing: use a JavaScript expression that returns the right value after `as`. The expression can be a function call: `f as vm.getValueToDisplay(f) for f in vm.festivities`. Yes, you can use the ternary operand. Any angular expression can be used.

Comment: nitpicking: The || operator will return the left side if left side is truthy, or the right side if left side is falsy.
Meaning, it won't necessarily return `false` when none of them is truthy.

Comment: @Tzafrir absolutely right. Don't know what I was thinking. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ng-options="f as f.alias && (f.name === null || f.name) for f in vm.festivities"
```

because you want `f.alias` to be not `null` and other expression can be `null`